# Form POST PHP. Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: php, html5

Tengo un problema a la hora de obtener los valores de un formulario mediante el método POST a un PHP.

El formulario está en una ventana modal creada con BootStrap:

```
<form action='../php/editCardPatient.php' method='POST' role="form" data-toggle="validator">
<div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
        <label for="inputName" class="control-label">Nombre</label>
        <input name='name' type="text" class="form-control" id="name" value="<?php 
            if(isset($_SESSION["name_patient"])) {
                echo $_SESSION["name_patient"];
            }?>" required disabled>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer" id='buttonAccept' style="display: none;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="funcionCancelCard()">Cancelar</button>
    <button type='submit' value='EditAcc' class="btn btn-primary" onclick="funcionButtons()">Aceptar</button>
</div></form>
```

Y en el fichero editCardPatient.php lo primero que hago es declarar las variables:

```
/* Recogemos las variables introducidas en el formulario de patientCard.php */
$nameCardPatient     = trim($_POST['name']);

/* Creamos la conexión BD */
include("../php/conectionBD.php");
session_start();
```

El problema es que en la página, cuando pulso el botón para enviar el formulario me aparece un error en la página PHP:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Se os ocurre que puede ser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El problema es que el campo está deshabilitado, los campos deshabilitados no son enviados por el formulario. En lugar de deshabilitarlo puedes ponerlo solo en "modo lectura".

```
<input name='name' type="text" class="form-control" id="name" value="<?php 
            if(isset($_SESSION["name_patient"])) {
                echo $_SESSION["name_patient"];
            }?>" required readonly="readonly">
```

Comment: Lo que tengo es un botón 'Editar' que lo que hace es dejar los campos habilitados para poder editarlos por el usuario y mediante el botón 'aceptar' llamo al php y a su vez a un javascript mediante onclick el cual vuelve a deshabilitar los campos.

¿Tendría que ponerle un setTimeout de un par de segundos a la función antes de deshabilitar los campos o hay algo más óptimo para poder hacer esto?

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Si el formulario no se envia a traves de AJAX, no veo motivo para deshabilitar los campos; si el efecto que quieres es que el usuario no siga editando los campos, en lugar de utilizar "disabled" para desactivar el campo, deberías utilizar "readonly"

Comment: genial, muchas gracias!!